# Перезагрузка страницы с очисткой кэша

Tags: javascript, битрикс, кэширование

На сайте (1С Битрикс) есть блок с 2-мя ссылками на одну и ту же страницу, но с разными передаваемыми параметрами.

```
<script>
 function reload_()
 {location.reload(true);}
</script>
<a href="/?site=link1" onclick="reload_()">Page 1</a>
<a href="/?site=link2" onclick="reload_()">Page 2</a>
```

Контент на странице отображается в зависимости от переданного параметра.
Дело в том, что кэш обновляется только после повторной перезагрузки страницы, а не сразу после клика по ссылке.
Можно это как-то реализовать?

Comment: Если информация выводится компонентом лучше отключите для него кэширование.

Comment: В лоб можно сделать если будет добавлять GET-параметр `clear_cache=Y`, но правильнее отключить кэширование такого компонента. Не всем компонентам его надо включать и это правильно.